# ActiveRecord: eagerly load, but only load ids

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Let's say I have these models:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
end
```

I'd like to load some Order records and their `#line_ids` in one request. I'd rather not instantiate all the Line records into ActiveRecord objects, though. Also, I'd rather not override the `#line_ids` method that ActiveRecord provides.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting a single column versus selecting a row shouldn't make much performance difference, unless you have many attributes on the Line model which may in turn be a hint for refactoring.

If you only want the id's, I would probably do something like this in my Order model

```
def line_ids_array
  Line.where(order_id: self.id).pluck(:id)
end
```

This should return an array of line id's for the particular order.

Comment: This overrides the `#line_ids` method that ActiveRecord provides, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: In that case, you can name it something else. I'm not sure exactly what it is you want. Structs? An array of id's? ActiveRecord instances with nil values on all by the id attribute?

Comment: Thanks for your help. AR provides `#{association}_ids` for each `has_many` association. If you eager load the association, calling `#line_ids`, for example, won't hit the database another time.

Comment: Also, I modified my question to be closer to what I actually want: to load multiple orders and their associated lines' id's at once.